# s3 event notifications are send more than one time per file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

1. I use Cloudfront to log client-side events.

   2. Those events are being saved into specific AWS S3 bucket.
   3. I have set "Event Notifications" for the bucket, calling specific AWS Lambda function whenever a file is created by any way.

**The problem:**

Somehow, I get duplicated, tripled and even more "events" of the same file (being "CompleteMultipartUpload") with the same event record as input to Lambda, over few seconds, up to few minutes from the first one.

**Questions:**

1. Why? Is it a bug? a feature?
2. Is there any way getting it once?

Thanks!

Comment: They only arrive once.  Have you verified that your Lambda function is not timing out or throwing an error?  Because if it does, Lambda will make two more attempts.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know it retries, but now I do see timeouts in the logs so it may be it. Perhaps the servers it calls are timed out, I'll try to enlarge the function duration and will update here and close the question if it works.

Comment: Well it seems to be it, but well enlarging the duration it keeps on retrying, so maybe I need to take a look on the server beforehand. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by  Michael above, when using s3 event notification with Lambda, you should mind to make sure that your endpoint does work as it should and sends a response, in case your Lambda code is waiting for one.

If you don't send a response and get a timeout after the specific timeout duration you set in the function, Lambda will retry two times more in the following seconds after the first try.